# How to install k-touch with terminal?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

How to install k-touch? And located for k-touch installer?

Answer (score 1):

Install  :

```
sudo apt-get install ktouch
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find [KTouch](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/ktouch/) in the Ubuntu Software Centre or you can install it through the terminal using:

To find & install ktouch:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-cache search ktouch
sudo apt-get install ktouch
```

Answer (score 0):

KTouch, the touch typing tutor for KDE is in the package [`ktouch`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ktouch) in the universe repositories.

Therefore

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ktouch
```

[image]